# using a winmd reference in javascript project

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-runtime

I am a beginner in Javascript. I am trying to use a WRC created in C# as a reference in javascript project i am writing. I am using the .winmd file that is generated as a reference in that js project. However i did not know how to invoke a method in that c# class or how to use that namespace in that C# class inside this js project. I referred online and could only find very scarce material.
The closest I could find was this:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/63534-C-and-JavaScript-working-together 
But this doesn't help with .winmd files.
Can anyone help me out. Links would be really helpful.
Thanks in Advance.